# add Custom fonts to Gantry Framework

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I am trying to add some custom fonts to Gantry Framework on Wordpress[Gantry](http://gantry.org/)

what i have done until now is :

In the wp-content/themes/my_theme_folder/custom/fonts folder i have uploaded my eot, ttf, svg, woff font files.

Then in the custom.scss file i have inserted the code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'war';
src: url('war-webfont-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('war-webfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern       Browsers */
url('war-webfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android,     iOS */
url('war-webfont-webfont.svg') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

I am trying to style an element through inspector:

```
p {font-family: 'war';}
```

but nothing happens. The font is beeing recognized (not strikethrough) but the font doesn't display.

Is this the correct way to insert custom fonts?

I have also followed the [Gantry Fonts Tutorial](http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/tutorials/fonts) but with no success either.

Answer (score 0):

The font name is the one you wrote in font-family property, so I think it should be:

```
p {font-family: 'din';}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the feedback, sorry this is my spelling mistake. I have edited to reflect the actual code. It is still not showing.

Comment: @xbass540 do you get some error on console like "failed to load resource"?

Comment: hi, how i forgot to check the console? you are right i got some GET errors regarding the fonts path. I corrected the path and the fonts appear. So for the Gantry framework to work it needs to enter the whole folder path.

Comment: @xbass540 Perfect! Anyway... this article could be very useful to understand how to set path in a css file: https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Answer (score 0):

In order for the fonts to work on Gantry Framework i inserted the CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('wp-content/themes/g5_hydrogen/custom/fonts/war-webfont-   webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('wp-content/themes/g5_hydrogen/custom/fonts/war-webfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
    url('wp-content/themes/g5_hydrogen/custom/fonts/war-webfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('wp-content/themes/g5_hydrogen/custom/fonts/war-webfont-webfont.svg') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

then i can easily use them by their name:

```css
p {font-family: myfont;}
```